# proof that $P(|X| +|Z| \ge a) \le P(|X| \ge a/2 ) +P( |Z| \ge a/2)$

Tags: probability

While studying another proof, I come across this step that i am no sure how to proof.

Proof that $P(|X| +|Z| \ge a) \le P(|X| \ge a/2) + P(|Z| \ge a/2)$

Comment: Note that there's nothing special about $a/2$ or the absolute values.  It's the case that $P(X+Z \geq x+z) \leq P(X \geq x) + P(Z \geq z)$ for any random variables $X,Z$ defined on the same space and real numbers $x,z$.

Comment: That seems somewhat suspect to me @BrianMoehring. Do you have a proof?

Comment: @AndrewZhang Structurally the proof is identical to angryavian's answer.  It comes down to $$((X(\omega) < x) \land (Z(\omega) < z)) \to (X(\omega)+Z(\omega) < x+z)$$ for any $\omega \in \Omega$ when $X,Z : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x,z\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(|X|+|Z| \ge a) \le P(\{|X| \ge a/2\} \cup \{|Z| \ge a/2\}) \le P(|X| \ge a/2) + P(|Z| \ge a/2)$$

For the first inequality, by taking the probability of complement events and reversing the inequality, it is equivalent to $P(|X| < a/2, |Z| < a/2) \le P(|X|+|Z| < a)$.

The second inequality is a union bound.